# PHP Warning starting PEAR - Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.so'

Tags: pear, redhat

Everytime I run PEAR, I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I've reviewed /etc/php.ini and not found any reference to php_mysql.so.  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ is my loadable extensions directory

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
```

No Dynamic Extensions are loaded.

No reference to this file in httpd.conf.

```
pear list

Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Console_Getopt   1.2.3   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.3   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this warning and how to fix it?

PEAR Version: 1.4.9
PHP Version: 5.2.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.2.0
Running on: Linux dedicated2 2.6.18-92.1.10.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jul 23 03:56:11 EDT 2008 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini, inspect the following:

extension_dir = "./"

OR

extension = php_mysql.so

Depending on your setup and what you have compiled into your php5, you might not need either line -- comment them out. The later will definitely lead to trying to load the module.